# Wildcard URL routing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am attempting to create a set of routes in laravel.  The first two are simple.

/ loads home
/12345 loads a result for 12345 via ResultController, which I accomplished with `{result}/`.

The third route I would like is /12345/foo/bar/baz, which eventually will execute a second controller that presents files.  Basically /foo/bar/baz represents the file location, so it could be any level of depth.  I would like to pass it to the controller as a single value.  I tried the below route to simply test that it would work:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home.main');
});
Route::get('{result}/', 'ResultController@showResult');
Route::get('{result}/(.*)', function() {
    return 'Huzzah!';
});
```

Currently, going to any path below {result}/ is still resulting in a 404.  For example:

```
/12345/foo -> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this but probably not a very good solution:

```
Other route declaration
Route::get('')

// At the bottom
Route::get('{result}/{any?}', function($result, $any = null) {

    // $any is optional
    if($any) {
        $paramsArray = explode('/', $any);
        // Use $paramsArray array for other parameters
    }

})->where('any', '(.*)');
```

Be careful, it can catch any `URL` that matches with this. Put this at the bottom of all routes.